# which to choose buffered reader or scanner from performance point of view

Tags: java, io

From aperformance optimization point of view: Reading a file in Java - is a buffered reader or scanner better?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class BufferedReaderExample {   

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //reading file line by line in Java using BufferedReader       
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("C:/sample.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            System.out.println("Reading File line by line using BufferedReader");

            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }           

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BufferedReaderExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BufferedReaderExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BufferedReaderExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
  } 

Output:
Reading File line by line using BufferedReader
first line in file
second line
third line
fourth line
fifth line
last line in file
```

and the other approach of scanner is..

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Javin Paul
 * Java program to read file line by line using Scanner. Scanner is a rather new
 * utility class in Java and introduced in JDK 1.5 and preferred way to read input
 * from console.
 */
public class ScannerExample {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException  {

       //Scanner Example - read file line by line in Java using Scanner
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/sample.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);

        //reading file line by line using Scanner in Java
        System.out.println("Reading file line by line in Java using Scanner");

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        scanner.close();
    }   

}

Output:
Reading file line by line in Java using Scanner
first line in file
second line
third line
fourth line
fifth line
last line in file
```

Comment: Remove a call to `println`, give it a file of 10+ megabytes, and see for yourself.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight please expalin in detail ..!!

Comment: You have your benchmark code written already, all you need to do is compare the time it takes to go through a large file (say, 10 GB) with both methods. I doubt that you would see a clear winner in this case, although I would go with a `BufferedReader` anyway.

Comment: @user1583868: Put `long ti = System.currentTimeMillis();` at the start and `System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - ti));` at the end of each version of the program and then run each with a large `sample.txt` and check which is faster...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BufferedReader` is a lot faster than `Scanner` because it `buffers the character` so you don't have to access the file each time you want to read a char from it.

Scanner are of particular use such as reading primitive data type directly and is also used for regular expressions.

I have used Scanner and BufferedReader both and BufferedReader gives significant fast performance. You can test it yourself too.

Comment: In jdk6 some version (do not remember which) Scanner has also a buffer of 1 KB, which is more then enough.